# Distance to a closed ball in a normed space.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $(E, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space, and consider $B = B[{\bf a},r]$ the closed ball. Let ${\bf b}\in E$. Then $\newcommand{\d}{{\rm d}} \d({\bf b},B) = 0$ if and only if ${\bf b} \in B$.

I managed to do it just fine, but I want to confirm something in one of the directions.. Silly, but better than letting it pass. Suppose that $\d({\bf b},B) = 0$. Then, for every $n \in \Bbb Z_{> 0}$ exists ${\bf x}_n \in B$ such that $\d({\bf b},{\bf x}_n) < \frac{1}{n}$. This way: $$\d({\bf a},{\bf b}) \leq \d({\bf a},{\bf x}_n)+\d({\bf b},{\bf x}_n) < r + \frac{1}{n},$$ so, taking the infimum, we get $\d({\bf a},{\bf b}) = r$, and we're done.

**Question:** the existence of the ${\bf x}_n$ is assured because $E$ is a normed vector space, right? Because I see this failing in an arbitrary metric space (a discrete one, for example), and I don't see where I used this hypothesis anywhere else (and I think the other direction is true in general).

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't  $d(b,B)=0$ mean that $\inf\{ d(b,x); x\in B\}=0$?

Comment: Yes.. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hence, for any $n$ there must be $x_n\in B$ such that $d(b,x_n)<\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Makes sense, but if that's the justificative, then where am I using that $E$ is a normed vector space?

Comment: It is not necessary that one has a normed space, it is enough to have a metric space. Of course, every normed space is also a metric space.

Comment: One more comment: your proof is ok, just change the conclusion, it is that $d(a,b)\leq r$, i.e., $b\in B$.

Comment: Oh, well. My bad. I wonder why the exercise stated a weaker result, then. Thanks for the help. If you want to pack up your comments and upgrade it to an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: It is ok, I have enjoyed thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just for organization and taking the question out of the unanswered list: as pointed by Janko Bracic in the comments, the result is valid for an arbitrary metric space. The existence of the ${\bf x}_n$ is assured by the definition of infimum only. And my conclusion in the end should have been ${\rm d}({\bf a},{\bf b}) \leq r$ instead of $= r$, it was a distraction of my part. The problem is now solved.

(disclaimer: I'm making this CW, not my credit.)